# Tomcat gets stuck on Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war] (DOCKER)

Tags: tomcat, docker

So I have a simple war file that I want to deploy on Docker, HelloWorld.war that I exported from NetBeans and is on my desktop, it gets stuck on

> 08-Jun-2017 06:59:20.276 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
>   p.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/weba
>   pps/HelloWorld.war]

OR takes too much time to for server startup or just doesn't work properly.

So the command I used is `docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -v $(pwd)/Desktop/HelloWorld.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/HelloWorld.war tomcat`

Is there anything wrong with my command?
I am relatively new to all these things so please bear.

The war file is exported from a project which works fine in Eclipse .
here are my container logs :

> Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat Using CATALINA_HOME:
>   /usr/local/tomcat Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat/temp Using
>   JRE_HOME:        /docker-java-home/jre Using CLASSPATH:
>   /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
>   08-Jun-2017 06:57:35.255 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version: 
>   Apache Tomcat/8.5.15 08-Jun-2017 06:57:35.258 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:
>   May 5 2017 11:03:04 UTC 08-Jun-2017 06:57:35.258 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:
>   8.5.15.0 08-Jun-2017 06:57:35.259 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:
>   Linux 08-Jun-2017 06:57:35.277 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:
>   4.4.66-boot2docker 08-Jun-2017 06:57:35.282 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:
>   amd64 08-Jun-2017 06:57:35.282 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre 08-Jun-2017 06:57:35.283 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM
>   Version:           1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-1~bpo8+1-b11 08-Jun-2017
>   06:57:35.283 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:
>   Oracle Corporation 08-Jun-2017 06:57:35.283 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:
>   /usr/local/tomcat 08-Jun-2017 06:57:35.284 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:
>   /usr/local/tomcat 08-Jun-2017 06:57:35.284 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
>   08-Jun-2017 06:57:35.284 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager 08-Jun-2017 06:57:35.285 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 08-Jun-2017 06:57:35.287
>   INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log
>   Command line argument:
>   -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources 08-Jun-2017 06:57:35.289 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat 08-Jun-2017 06:57:35.290
>   INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log
>   Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat 08-Jun-2017
>   06:57:35.291 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp 08-Jun-2017
>   06:57:35.294 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded
>   APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.12] using APR version
>   [1.5.1]. 08-Jun-2017 06:57:35.295 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR
>   capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false],
>   random [true]. 08-Jun-2017 06:57:35.297 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent
>   APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
>   08-Jun-2017 06:57:35.315 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL
>   successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.0e  16 Feb 2017] 08-Jun-2017
>   06:57:35.558 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init
>   Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] 08-Jun-2017
>   06:57:35.635 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a
>   shared selector for servlet write/read 08-Jun-2017 06:57:35.644 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"] 08-Jun-2017 06:57:35.651 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a
>   shared selector for servlet write/read 08-Jun-2017 06:57:35.664 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization
>   processed in 2405 ms 08-Jun-2017 06:57:35.728 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting
>   service [Catalina] 08-Jun-2017 06:57:35.729 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet
>   Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.15 08-Jun-2017 06:57:35.856 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web
>   application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/HelloWorld.war]

Comment: we use https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin for those things, I guess you are using JAVA too, so... maybe is a easy way for you to go :) 

if not, I only know how to do that with a Dockerfile where you add the entry point and so on...

Comment: But I have already built the war file using eclipse ; which is installed in my system.

Comment: Try removing all other war's that come with tomcat installation, you might keep manager one, but examples, docs, root can be removed, try and check.

Comment: Thats not helping (ViS)

Comment: I had a similar issue, and adding this line to catalina.sh helped:
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"

Comment: @PeterPetrekanics I want to run a jar with embedded tomcat, but tomcat gets stuck when starting. Is there any way to pass this JAVA_OPTS as command line arguments when running maven like mvn clean package JAVA_OPS or when executing jar like java -jar X.X.X.jar JAVA OPS. Or may be pass this arguments via java program?

Comment: Hi @DashrathChauhan, could you please provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.
I am asking this because the urandom workaround should no longer be necessary:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59564269/deprecated-java-security-egd-file-dev-urandom-for-spring-boot-applications

Comment: Hi @PeterPetrekanics, I have fixed it. Actually I was running some initial db scripts after starting tomcat which were causing this issue; found it after some debugging and logging. And yes you are right this urandom workaround is no longer necessary, I have verified this by running standalone jar on another machine and it worked like charm. Anyways thanks for some insights.