# Deprecated java.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom for Spring Boot applications?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, tomcat

I used to configure `-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom` in my Dockerfile for Spring Boot applications.

In https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/ (or GitHub https://github.com/dsyer/gs-spring-boot-docker) a comment was added that this is not required any more for newer versions:

> To reduce Tomcat startup time we added a system property pointing to "/dev/urandom" as a source of entropy. This is not necessary with more recent versions of Spring Boot, if you use the "standard" version of Tomcat (or any other web server).

I am looking for any references for this change in Tomcat or Spring Boot repos, and which Spring Boot versions are affected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem should have been resolved by the JDK Enhancement Proposal : [JEP 123, Configurable Secure Random-Number Generation](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/123).

According to the [JDK 8 Security Enhancements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/enhancements-8.html) official Oracle document, the `/dev/./urandom` workaround is no more necessary from JDK 8.

> SHA1PRNG and NativePRNG were fixed to properly respect the SecureRandom seed source properties in the java.security file. (The obscure workaround using file:///dev/urandom and file:/dev/./urandom is no longer required.)