# securerandom.source vs java.security.egd Java System properties difference

Tags: java, security, random, java-17

I turns out that not possible to find full list of Java properties other than [basic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

I want to understand difference of `securerandom.source` vs `java.security.egd`

When I run printing out from within Java main method:

```java
System.out.println("Secure random source: " + Security.getProperty("securerandom.source"));
System.out.println("java.security.egd: " + System.getProperty("java.security.egd"));
```

I get (on JDK 17):

```
Secure random source: file:/dev/random
java.security.egd: null
```

JDK 11 https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/oracle-providers.html#GUID-9DC4ADD5-6D01-4B2E-9E85-B88E3BEE7453
and JDK 17 https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/security/oracle-providers.html#GUID-C4706FFE-D08F-4E29-B0BE-CCE8C93DD940
both say `file:/dev/random` is already default, and setting it is not needed.

> if the entropy gathering device in java.security is set to file:/dev/urandom or file:/dev/random, then NativePRNG is preferred to SHA1PRNG

But NativePRNG algorithm is already used by default:

```java
SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
System.out.println("Algorithm: " + secureRandom.getAlgorithm());
```

Output

```
Algorithm: NativePRNG
```

My feelings are that specifying `java.security.egd` is not needed,
but I cannot get documentation prove of it.

The https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/enhancements-8.html
says

> SHA1PRNG and NativePRNG were fixed to properly respect the SecureRandom seed source properties in the java.security file.  The obscure workaround using file:///dev/urandom and file:/dev/./urandom is no longer required

But it does not say, there is no need to use `java.security.egd`.

**What is `securerandom.source` vs `java.security.egd` Java System properties difference  ?**

Yes, this is [older staff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20315022/java-slow-entropy-related-issue) in [many places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59564269/deprecated-java-security-egd-file-dev-urandom-for-spring-boot-applications)

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/HowTo+FasterStartUp (last edit 2017)
has

> There is a way to configure JRE to use a non-blocking entropy source by setting the following system property: -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it does not say, there is no need to use java.security.egd.

I think you've hit the nail on the head.

First, searching "EGD" in `$JAVA_HOME/conf/security/java.security` provides documentation for `securerandom.source`, not for `java.security.egd`.

Second, that documentation states:

> By default, an attempt is made to use the entropy gathering device specified by the "securerandom.source" Security property.
>
> The entropy gathering device can also be specified with the System property "java.security.egd".
>
> Specifying this System property will override the "securerandom.source" Security property.

From these two clues I understand the official setting is `securerandom.source` and that `java.security.egd` is still supported for compatibility reasons.

Full quote:

```ini
#
# Sun Provider SecureRandom seed source.
#
# Select the primary source of seed data for the "NativePRNG", "SHA1PRNG"
# and "DRBG" SecureRandom implementations in the "Sun" provider.
# (Other SecureRandom implementations might also use this property.)
#
# On Unix-like systems (for example, Linux/MacOS), the
# "NativePRNG", "SHA1PRNG" and "DRBG" implementations obtains seed data from
# special device files such as file:/dev/random.
#
# On Windows systems, specifying the URLs "file:/dev/random" or
# "file:/dev/urandom" will enable the native Microsoft CryptoAPI seeding
# mechanism for SHA1PRNG and DRBG.
#
# By default, an attempt is made to use the entropy gathering device
# specified by the "securerandom.source" Security property.  If an
# exception occurs while accessing the specified URL:
#
#     NativePRNG:
#         a default value of /dev/random will be used.  If neither
#         are available, the implementation will be disabled.
#         "file" is the only currently supported protocol type.
#
#     SHA1PRNG and DRBG:
#         the traditional system/thread activity algorithm will be used.
#
# The entropy gathering device can also be specified with the System
# property "java.security.egd". For example:
#
#   % java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/random MainClass
#
# Specifying this System property will override the
# "securerandom.source" Security property.
#
# In addition, if "file:/dev/random" or "file:/dev/urandom" is
# specified, the "NativePRNG" implementation will be more preferred than
# DRBG and SHA1PRNG in the Sun provider.
#
securerandom.source=file:/dev/random
```